# SlidingDrawer in the FrameLayout

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, android-framelayout

I have an activity with FrameLayout in the root. Now I'd like to add SlidingDrawer in it. The problem is when I open SlidingDrawer I can see elements that are currently displayed in FrameLayout. It looks ok if I set background color to SlidingDrawer, but when I touching opened SlidingDrawer, my touches are passed to views under it. How I can disable passing touches to views that are under SlidingDrawer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Onclicklistener for the elements that are inside your sliding drawer, this would solve your problem.